# Can Editable Template work on old archetype i.e AEM 6.1?

Tags: aem

Actually we want to expose some of our content to a third party, so what we thought best is using a experience fragment and I have read that experience fragments actually work only on Editable templates. The question here is whether editable template can work on old archetype i.e AEM 6.1 as we cannot use the latest archetypes due to various reasons. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Experience fragment can work as a standalone component, it does not need Editable template to work. It is the feature introduced in AEM 6.3. You should look at different approach for you requirement.

Comment: For your requirement you can expose a json structure from a servlet instead of experience fragment.